# Diophantine equation of 2nd order

Tags: arithmetic, diophantine-equations, integers

So I have a test in arithmetics tomorrow and was exercising a bit, until I came across this problem:

> Solve: 
>                                     $$x^2 = 4y^2 +3$$ 
>   where $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$.

My knowledge in this field is very limited (I'm only aware of Bezout's, theorem fo GCDs, Gauss's theorem ($a\mid bc$ and $a∧b=1 \iff a|c$), and Fermat's little theorem, so I'd appreciate clarification).

Comment: What is $Z^2$ and do you mean solve $x^2=4y^2+3$?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout (Z)^2==> (X, Y) and both are integers

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout and yes, I tried to make some space but the app messed it up I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$x^2-4y^2=(x-2y)(x+2y)=3$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Well,  that means "x-2y|3" and "x+2y|3", and for some reason I get "x=-2y" and I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for.  And by the way,  (x=3;y=1) is a solution, can't I use that?

Comment: Remember that $x,y$ are integers. Now, the equation is telling you that two integers, $x-2y$ and $x+2y$, multiplied makes $3$. What can you say about these integers? Also, $x=3, y=1$ is not a solution, since $9\neq 7$.

Also, you're right that both of them divides $3$, but you can deduce even more.

Comment: So I thought about it and, we either get (x-2y=3 and x+2y=1, or -3 and -1) or (x-2y=1 and x+2y=3, or -1 and -3) right?

Comment: Exactly! And those are the only possible options since $3=1\cdot 3=(-1)\cdot (-3)$. Since you got $x^2$ and $y^2$ in your expression, you only have to consider if $(1,3)$ or $(3,1)$ are solutions (since the negatives vanish when you square them).

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The equation $x^2 = 4 z+3$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes, I just realized it a while ago, thanks!